# How to call a constructor in the client?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to code a program that takes the users input and creates a rectangle. The program will validate the users input is a valid rectangle and if so will output the Area and Perimeter. The first screenshot is the Test client and the second is the main. When I run Rectangle.java it compiles fine, but when I compile Test.java it says, "error: cannot find symbol boolean result = ValidRectangle (width, length);" It says the ValidRectangle, Area, and Perimeter could not be found. Help! Not sure why it does not automatically recognize the constructor in Rectangle.java

I've tried to google this error, but not finding much help. I thought that it would automatically recognize the constructor?

//Rectangle.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {

/*Validates that the rectangle is acceptable*/

public static boolean ValidRectangle (double width, double length) {

    if (width + length > 30)

        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/*Calculates the area of the rectangle*/

public static double Area (double width, double length) {
    return (width * length);
}

/*Calculates the perimeter of the rectangle*/

public static double Perimeter (double width, double length) {
    return (2 * (width + length));
}
```

}

//Test.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter the width of the rectangle : ");
    double width = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.print ("Enter the length of the rectangle : ");
    double length = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println ("Entered Width : "+width);
            System.out.println ("Entered length : "+length);

    boolean result = ValidRectangle (width, length);

    if(result==false)
         System.out.println("This is invalid rectangle. Try 
                 again...");
    else {
         System.out.println("Area : "+Area (width, length));
         System.out.println("Perimeter : "+Perimeter (width, 
                 length));
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: If you want to call the static `ValidRectangle` method, you want `boolean result = Rectangle.ValidRectangle(width, length);`. This has nothing to do with _"constructors"_

Comment: Thank you! That helped it make more sense. I called the ValidRectangle method, but if I wanted to call the area method would it be something like, "double Area = Rectangle.Area(width, length);"  ?

Answer (score 2):

`ValidRectangle` is a method that belongs to the class `Rectangle`. `ValidRectangle` is static, so you do not have to instantiate a `Rectangle` object. You can call it like this:

```
boolean result = Rectangle.ValidRectangle(width, length);
```

As a side note, I recommend you follow a popular Java code style convention, such as [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). Specifically, you should [name your methods](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.3-method-names) using [lowerCamelCase](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Rectangle.ValidRectangle(width, length);` or you could add an import static statement that will allow you to call all static functions in Rectangle without referencing it: `import static (package containing Rectangle).Rectangle;`

Answer (score 0):

you should import the static method 
add import static before your code " public class Test " like below

```
...
import static your.package.Rectangle.ValidRectangle ;
public class Test {...
```

...